# Check if Azure Store Account is encrypted

Tags: c#, azure, encryption

I would like to check if Azure Store Account is encrypted.

Unfortunately this return true always, even if the storage account is not encrypted. What is wrong?

```
bool IsEncrypted(IStorageAccount storageAccount)
{
     var encryptionKeySource = storageAccount.EncryptionKeySource;
     var encryptionService = storageAccount.EncryptionStatuses[StorageService.Blob];
     return encryptionService.IsEnabled;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by encrypted? Storage accounts are encrypted at rest by default, but you can choose to to encrypt it with your own key (BYOK).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption

Comment: "Can I disable encryption on my storage account?"

"Encryption is enabled by default, and there is no provision to disable encryption for your storage account."

Comment: OK, so I could just list if there is a default Microsoft's key or user's one. Can I distinguish it somehow?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already are on the right path in your solution. If I understand [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage.fluent.storageaccountencryptionkeysource?view=azure-dotnet) correctly, `encryptionKeySource` will give you the info you are looking for:

1. `encryptionKeySource == StorageAccountEncryptionKeySource.Microsoft_KeyVault` ==> BYOK (user defined key resides in Azure Key Vault)
2. `encryptionKeySource == StorageAccountEncryptionKeySource.Microsoft_Storage` ==> Microsoft-managed encryption key.